# jQuery validations rules not fonctionnal

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I need to verify that the new title for a board isn't already used in my database using jQuery.
But I have several troubles:

1. I can see an error when the title is less than three characters (which is good) but the error doesn't dissapear once I introduced more characters.
2. It kept saying that the title already exist in my database when it doesn't AND when it does.

Here's my script code:

```
<script src="lib/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-validation-1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#boardForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        board_title: {
                            remote: {
                                url: "allboards/title_available_service",
                                type: "post",
                                data: {
                                    board_title: function() {
                                        return $("#board_title").val();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            minlength: 3
                        }
                    },
                messages: {
                    board_title: {
                        remote: "This title is already taken.",
                        minlength: "The title must be at least 3 characters."
                    }
                }
            });

            $("form input:first").focus();

        });
        </script>
```

and here's my form:

```
<form id="boardForm" method="post" action="allboards/update_board" >
    <input id='board_title' name='board_title' type="text" value="<?= $board->getTitle();?>">
    <input type='text' id='edit_board_title' name='edit_board_title' value='<?= $board->getBoard_id(); ?>' hidden>
    <button type="submit"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i></button>
    <div class="ferrors" id="errTitle"></div>
</form>
```

which connect to this php code in my controller

```
public function title_available_service(){
        $res = "true";
        if(isset($_POST["board_title"]) && $_POST["board_title"] !== ""){
            $board = Board::board_by_title($_POST["board_title"]);
            if($board){
                $res = "false";
            }
        }

        echo $res;
    }
```

and here the function board_by_title in the model

```
public static function board_by_title($title){
        $query = self::execute("SELECT * FROM board WHERE Title = :Title", array("Title"=>$title));
        $data = $query->fetch();
        return new Board($data['Title'], $data['Owner'], $data['CreatedAt'], 
        $data['ModifiedAt'], $data['ID']);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are a number of issues here and they really need to be split up. It sounds like you need help with jQuery and the PHP side. It's difficult to answer easily. I'd suggest you break the question up to just look at the API for now  to see if that's working correctly.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is the JS code not working as expected, or is this a PHP problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase it seems like the remote refuse to take the value of my input board_title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to problem #2, there are a couple of things that could cause your issue.

1. Maybe the $_POST value is not as you expect it.
2. Maybe your `Board` class returns *something* even when the `$data` array is empty. And that *something* is treated as a boolean true in your if statement.

Try the following code to test for either of those scenarios:

```
public function title_available_service(){
        $res = "true";

# First check what $_POST actually contains
var_dump($_POST);exit;
//Make sure it contains the "board_title" key and that the key has a value
//if not your below if will return false

        if(isset($_POST["board_title"]) && $_POST["board_title"] !== ""){
            $board = Board::board_by_title($_POST["board_title"]);

# Add the below line, and see if the value is true or false
var_dump((bool)$board);exit;
//if true regardless of the board title, then that's your problem

            if($board){
                $res = "false";
            }
        }

        echo $res;
    }
```

Finally, you don't need to write `if(isset($_POST["board_title"]) && $_POST["board_title"] !== "")`, for your purposes, a simple `if($_POST["board_title"])` will suffice to ensure there is a value set.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried adding that part but the fonction keeps saying true no matter what I insert

Comment: Right, in which case, your first `if` statement is returning false. I have updated my answer to check for that also.

Comment: Open Developer tools in your browser (Press `F12`), click on the Network tab and watch when the AJAX call is made to see what content it has. It seems like your problem is in your jQuery. I don't see anything wrong with it, but I'm not an expert in jQuery!

Comment: I finally found out. The problem was becaause the function in my model wasn't taking in account the case if my fetch didn't bring anything, thank you very much  for your help :)

Comment: Wonderful, happy to help!